# Cannot deploy Ruby on Rails application to AWS, with 'mini_racer'-related error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

Deploying my application to AWS with the 'bundle exec cap production deploy' command, I got following error:

```
00:15 bundler:install
      01 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle insta…
      01 Unable to find a spec satisfying mini_racer …
      01 lockfile is corrupted?
bundle exit status: 7 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Unable to find a spec satisfying mini_racer (>= 0) in the set. Perhaps the
lockfile is corrupted?
```

I checked and tried every version of 'mini_racer', but got the same errors. Can someone help?

Following are the gems related to my question. I will add more information if needed.

Thank you.

Gemfile

```
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

Gemfile.lock

```
mini_racer (0.3.0)
  libv8 (> 8.4)
  mini_racer
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.20
```

Comment: I found out by myself: Versions of the bundler between local and EC2 was different. The problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem before. So just removed using mini_racer, decided to install nodeJs in docker.

Comment: Thank you togi, I just found out the cause of the problem!: Versions of the bundler between local and EC2 was different.

Comment: After fixing this difference deployment went well.